# jquery .get data manipulation

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using below code to get a page:

```
$.get('http://example.com/page1.html', function (data) {

});
```

Now lets imagine there is a #content div inside that page1.html and I need to read it's inner html as I already have #content div on page where Ajax call is occurring.

What is the right way to do this? I've tried with:

```
data = $(data).find('#content').html();
$("#content").empty().append(data);
```

But it seems that html() function is not the right one as it returns null, while contents() is returning data but I am not skillful enough to get only what I need from it.

Any help appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: can u show structure of data I mean data sample

Comment: `<html><body><div id="content">etc.</div></body></html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
var content = $("#content", data).html(); // or var content = $("#content", $(data)).html();

$("#content").html(content);
```

EDIT:  How about this?

```
$('#content').load("http://example.com/page1.html #content");
```

From: http://api.jquery.com/load/ - "loading page fragments".

Comment: thanks Stefan, I did that way myself last night. I was trying to do it through get so I didn't have to wrap content inside extra container.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
data = $(data).find('#content').html();
```

return null when data is

```
var data ="<div id='content'>my data</div>";
```

because `#content` already parent, if data is

```
var data ="<div><div id='content'>my data</div><div>";
```

then return exact html because this time #content is child and you can .find() this in parent div.

Comment: how about this.. it returns nothing no matter of your search query. as an example $(data).html() will return null while $(data).contents() will return some data but not in a controlled way.